# An unexpected error has occurred when adding new Item

Tags: restore, content-migration

I sort have an issue here. Recently we have done a database restore in SharePoint 2013 with data coming from a SP2010 site. All of our Lists, Content Types etc are present. However, upon clicking the NewForm.aspx link to add a new item to a list, we are getting "An unexpected error has occurred.".

We would like to avoid deleting the Custom List and recreating it as it contains lots of production data.

Note that I already have exported the list as a template. Once uploaded to the list template gallery in SP2013 and once created a new list based on the same, I'm still getting the unexpected error.

How can this be resolved best?

Many thanks!